# how to set x-axis ticks as date in matplotlib when draw a ax.twin plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

my data is:

[image]

I can plot an ax.twinx bar and line plot use following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [350, 200, 150, 475],'b': [43, 3, 27, 10],'date':pd.date_range('2018-01-01',periods=4)},columns=['date','a','b'])
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
ax2=ax1.twinx()
df['b'].plot(kind='bar', color='y', ax=ax1)
df['a'].plot(kind='line', marker='d', ax=ax2)
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax1.yaxis.tick_left()
ax1.legend(loc=0)
ax2.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

and the result is like this:
[image]

but I want to put the date variable in x-axis ticks which are [0,1,2,3] now , so I tried the code:

```
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(df['date'])
```

but it showed error as follow:
[image]

so how can I do to show the date in x ticks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(df['date'])` with:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(df['date'])
```

To have a different date format, you can use this line to change your date column:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: @yogazining you are welcome :) dont forget to upvote the answer as well :)